# Matplotlib: Change the locator of an appended axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a number of data images like the one below, in which I appended a new set of axes to the right to force the colorbar to be the same size as the image.
[image]

The ticks on the colorbar are too close together, so I'd like to reduce their number.  I attempted to do it this way:

```
# Set up colorbar
divider = make_axes_locatable(plt.gca())
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
cax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plticker.LinearLocator(numticks=5))
cbar = plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
cbar.set_label(cbtitle, **cbkw)
```

I know that, in general, re-formatting axes in this way requires a call to a `cbar.update_axis()` to force the update, but that didn't seem to work here.  `cax` is an Axes object, and calling `cbar.update_axis()` doesn't do anything either.  In fact, both strategies, as well as leaving the update out, result in the image above.  Does anybody know how I can reduce the ticks?

Comment: Although this doesn't answer your question in any way, note that the jet colormap must die: http://researchweb.watson.ibm.com/people/l/lloydt/color/color.HTM

Comment: This is the spectral colormap.

Comment: Still, the rainbowish colormaps - however they are called - are not well suited for continuous data visualization. In short: Colorblind people will have problems, they tend to show hard boarders where there aren't any and they have a non monotonous brightness, which leads to weird black/white printing and misidentification of important regions and they have no intrinsic order. They are ok for discrete data, which should be distinguishable but not ordered in any way. But this is  still off-topic. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample code contains a lot of variables which are defined outside of it, so its hard to see all the things you're doing. But with regard to setting the number of ticks on the cbar, this works for me:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow(np.random.randn(10,10), interpolation='none')

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
cbar = plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax, ticks=mpl.ticker.LinearLocator(numticks=3))
```

[image]

@hildensia, the image shows the result of chopping a rainbow in squares and placing them randomly in a grid, so i really needed the 'jet' cmap, sorry. ;) You're right though, off course.